# Image hover effect - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted to know if there are any jquery plugins which can perform a similar operation(i.e show text)  on hover as seen on http://gridonic.ch/?g=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at mosaic;

http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0/

Answer (score 1):

This can help you.

```
$('.div img').hover(
function(){
 $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'-25px',}, 300); 
},
function(){
 $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'0px',}, 300);
}
```

);

This query will have the same effect as what you want.

To explain the code

.div = class fo your div or any element

```
function(){
 $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'-25px',}, 300); 
},
```

this code means when the image is hover it will move upward direction with the help of marginTop:'-25px'

and the code

```
function(){
 $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'0px',}, 300);
}
```

it means when it not on hover or on mouse out of the image it will return to its original position.

You can play around with the data on how fast you want it to be or any position you want it to be.